# React Native | Unable to start receiver com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, google-play-console

Issue found in Google Play Store Pre-launch report

the detailed exception stack trace is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{7f7aa4f u0a192 TRNB bg:+1m35s375ms idle change:uncached procs:4 seq(0,0,0)}
```

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{7f7aa4f u0a192 TRNB bg:+1m35s375ms idle change:uncached procs:4 seq(0,0,0)}
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4035)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400 (ActivityThread.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1924)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7664)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:592)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{7f7aa4f u0a192 TRNB bg:+1m35s375ms idle change:uncached procs:4 seq(0,0,0)}
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1715)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1670)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:720)
  at alj.a (PG:2)
  at alm.a (PG:3)
  at wnv.a (PG:2)
  at com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver.onReceive (PG:6)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:4026)
```

**"react-native": "0.70.1"**

Comment: Is this a programming problem to be solved or a bug report? If the former, show what you're doing, your attempts to resolve the error, and an [mre] if appropriate. If this is a bug report, file an issue with Google and add an answer explaining that it is a bug with a link to your bug report so that others encountering will know it's not their mistake.

Comment: I am also having the same issue in the Google play console Pre-launch receiver